# How to install a Desktop Environment on Ubuntu after basic server installation

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, kde

I downloaded Ubuntu-Server 12.04.3 LTS and cut a CD. Installed it, logged in as user, `sudo -i` as root.

The basic installation has no desktop environment or so it appears. I did some reading and for good or bad, opted to go with KDE. I also read on options between installing Kubuntu vs. installing Ubuntu and then KDE. I do not have an internet connection now to the machine because I am not able to have the dongle installed and I think that it expects some DTE or X-Window to be present to get it up. That's another problem but the fact relevant to this question is that I don't have net connectivity for now. I do have other machines with Internet connection. So, I can get any software downloaded, copied and installed to this machine or have some Samba shares to get the downloaded files across.

I read somewhere that KDE can be about 1 GB and I find that rather unbelievable for a Desktop Environment. My question though is what do I need to do now to get KDE installed?

I tried `apt-get install`, but I think that expects net connection. I wonder if some DTE is on the CD that I can install? The CD is mounted and I can browse through it using basic shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a suitable ubuntu install cd with the packages you need to install the desktop environment (e.g. kubuntu or xubuntu iso). Add the cdrom as an apt package source using apt-cdrom:

```
apt-cdrom add /media/cdrom
```

After that apt-get can be used to install the packages on that cd, which should include what you need to install a desktop environment.

Comment: Yes the downloaded server install is a ISO9660 CD so I did what you asked me and that part worked fine. But apt-get install kde or apt-get install kde-full gives the error "E: Unable to locate package kde."  Apt-get install unity gave the same result too. So, how do I proceed now? I tried to get some download from kde.org but just too many links and too confusing to get binary downloads. Any suggestion? I would still prefer to start with Ubuntu and not Kubuntu

Comment: The server install does NOT include the desktop environment packages. Download the _appropriate_ desktop install cd (ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu etc.)

Comment: Is there some package in it that can at least give some basic Xwindow terminal? This is required for the net dongle to work. Once I get the dongle on it to work, I can use apt-get to download from the net and install.

Comment: what about kubuntu-desktop for kde? xubuntu-desktop for xfce? lubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-desktop as well

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Hopefully no more questions. I downloaded and got Ubuntu Desktop on a CD. I did a apt-cdrom but any "apt-get install" after that just complaints "Unable to locate package..." Any thoughts?